# How to create a Mobile App property through the Google Analytics Admin Console for ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-analytics, analytics

Based on this, to use google analytics we need to create Mobile App property through the Google Analytics Admin Console

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-analytics/

However, in google analytics, it says would need to have Firebase

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO5J2.png

Question is whether google analytics for ionic does not work anymore ? Should we use Firebase instead ? if so how for analytics ? Or how do we go about this for having ionic app analytics ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using Firebase Analytics using the Ionic Firebase plugin and it is working great! The plugin is available [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/) and you'll be able to see the analytics in Firebase at `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/<your-project-name>/analytics/overview`.

Comment: thanks will try. for ionic, do i add in firebase ios, android or webapp ?

Comment: i got it working on my ionic v1 app. but how do i actually check for specific event triggers. I tried to issue some logEvent and setScreenName like this: https://dpaste.de/htb1 but nothing seems to come out except some general analytics https://imgur.com/a/XFjcnpx

Comment: Those triggers must not be firing. Maybe check that the plugin is initialized. `if (window.FirebasePlugin) {...} else {console.log('No Firebase plugin')}`